# How activate Data Flow(Preview) in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factories but Data Flow (Preview) is not avaliable in my Data Factory. How could I activate this resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the [Get-Start document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create) to create V2 data factory, the Data Flow Preview feature is supported by V2 version.

[image]

Also,you could submit the infomation in this [page](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR0bW_1HTuLVCg-zA7dpw8gFURFFCR04yQUpLTThXRktQV0VLREFWVTRBWi4u).

Then you could create your Data Flow in the ADF UI.

[image]